# Is RabbitMQ necessary for the project I want to write?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I'm writing a project but I can't decide if I need RabbitMQ here.

I have an api that accepts tickets. Here I accept an object with only 2 properties. I need to write this to the database and then check if the tickets are canceled every 10 minutes and delete the canceled ones. I am stuck between 2 options.

The first is to write the incoming tickets directly to the database and check those tickets every 10 minutes with a background job and delete the canceled ones.

The second option is to send the incoming tickets to RabbitMQ and then read the tickets from that RabbitMQ from the job and write the ones that have not been canceled to the database.

Which of these 2 options is better? Will RabbitMQ produce a noticeable performance here? Or in this case I don't need it? Please note that up to 10,000 tickets can be posted to me per day.

If RabbitMQ absolutely needs it, RabbitMQ sends the message it receives that minute, and I need to receive and check it 10 minutes later. Is there a configuration in RabbitMQ that adjusts this? Because it doesn't matter if the ticket comes to me at that moment, can RabbitMQ send a message repeatedly after a certain time? I only need to check after 10 minutes and then delete from RabbitMQ.

Thanks

Comment: There is no isolated problem that can only be solved with one particular named product. What you're describing sounds like a problem where performance shouldn't be a big consideration regardless of technology. You're dealing with a small amount of data accessed infrequently. If you're not going out of your way to handle it inefficiently, anything will do. At 10k messages every day checked every 10 minutes you could linearly scan them every single time and it'd still be fast enough.

Comment: Everything that RabbitMQ does can also be programmed by you. The question is does RabbitMQ make your programming task easier for example because programming it by yourself takes to much effort. That is hard to tell from the outside depends on knowledge and experience in programming and the problem you try to solve.

Comment: The options are not equivalent. The first allow cancellation of tickets of any age, while using a queue only allow cancellation of tickets 10minutes old or less. When it comes to performance the best alternative is usually to just test both alternatives. Do not expect random people on the internet to provide a detailed performance analysis of your specific use case. But 10k items/day are not *that* many, so you could most likely make either alternative work.